# ASP.NET continuous data streaming suggestion

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, duplex

I have a problem.

I have a client server setup. My client wants to share data (binary) with all other clients. I don't want to have an extra database layer primarily because I don't have the need for storing the data and secondary, I want to skip the latency due to database communication.

Currently, I have a desktop implementation wherein I play with TCP sockets. I want to implement a web based solution for it.

The application is similar to a text chat application, just that in this case the data to be transferred is bigger and the frequency is more and the clients are many.

I was looking at WCF Duplex implementation, but since I have never done it before, I wanted to be sure if that is the way to go.

Can anyone please help me with few implementations of this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is bit confusing for me. You mentioned client server setup and then you said that your client would be sharing data with other clients. Can you please explain your setup in a more elaborate form please?

Comment: Okay. The server, actually, is there to relay the data to all the clients.

Comment: Let them connect to a web service and you can send/receive whatever you need to. If it has to be really fast go with sockets.

Comment: How can I use sockets in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Duplex Implementation would work for you as I had used the same for the sort of problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The problem is that there would be many discreet groups of clients, each wanting to share the data only amongst that group. Can a single instance of WCF take care of relaying the data to different groups? Like, lets assume implementing a group text chat. There would be many groups, with many clients in each group. Something like that..

Comment: You can assign token to different groups where clients in a certain group would share the same token and then in the service side code, depending upon the token presented by clients, you can send the appropriate data.

Comment: Would this be better than the traditional TCP sockets?

Answer (score 2):

You talked about sharing data to many users in what sounds like a broadcast scenario and also a web based solution.. What about an RSS feed?

Comment: That is more of a 1 to many implementation though, are all clients able to share (send) or just yours?